# Recursive definition of recursively defined operations

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, exponentiation, tetration

The recursive definitions of addition, multiplication, and exponentiation usually stop after exponentiation ("${\small+}1$" to be read as "the successor of"):

$x \boldsymbol{+} (y\ {\small+}1) := (x \boldsymbol{+} y)\ {\small+}1$

$x \times (y\ {\small+}1) := (x \times y) \boldsymbol{+} x$

$x$ ^ $(y\ {\small+}1) := (x$ ^ $y) \times x$

Sometimes, this seems due to a lack of symbols, only. But it seems feasible to define a recursive sequence of operations $\circ_i$:

$x \circ_{i{\small+}1}  (y\ {\small +}1) := (x \circ_{i{\small+}1} y) \circ_{i} x$

with

$x \circ_{0} y := x\ {\small+}1 $

> Where resp. under which name is this **sequence of operations** 
>   investigated?

And:

> Why is it - eventually - O.K. to stop after exponentiation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_operator

Comment: Here some interesting links of questions about Hyp. at MSC:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388217/are-hyperoperators-primitive-recursive/388265#388265
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170398/does-anything-precede-incrementation-in-the-operator-hierarchy/346004#346004
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390091/has-this-phenomenon-been-discovered-and-named/393521#393521
And About Commutative Hyperoperations:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383168/where-can-i-learn-more-about-commutative-hyperoperations/389646#389646

Comment: As Asaf say this sequenque is investigated under the name of Hyperoperations with other similar sequences like the commutative Hyperoperations.

Answer (score 2):

As Stephen points out, these operations are given by the [three-argument Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#History), plugging in 0 (for addition), 1 (for multiplication), *etc.* to the third argument.

Another notation used for the same thing is Knuth's [up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation): it starts with $a \mathbin{\uparrow} b$ to denote $a^b$ and continues by denoting the next functions in the sequence with multiple arrows: $a \mathbin{\uparrow\uparrow} b$, $a \mathbin{\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow} b$, *etc.*

Answer (score 0):

It is called the Ackermann function (or some variant thereof).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function

Comment: I did not ask for a *specific* function. (Do you mean $\circ_4$, eventually? I asked for the *sequence* $\circ_i, i = 0, 1,\dots$)

Comment: @HansStricker A function $\mathbb{N}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{N}$ naturally corresponds to a sequence of functions $\mathbb{N}^n \to \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I thought you were asking for the name under which this function is investigated.  If you read the web page I posted, you will see that Ackermann's original function had three arguments.  It also calls it Knuth's up-arrow notation.